# Gitlab compare results wrong after squashed merge

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using my organization's Gitlab (13.10) and just performed a merge (for simplicity, I renamed the branches, merging `branch2` back into `branch1`, and updated the html views). `branch2` had 69 commits affecting 42 files, `branch1` added only one file in one commit. I selected "squash commits" to have all the changes in one commit on `branch1`.

[image]

I pulled that locally and entered `git diff origin/branch2..origin/branch1`, and as expected, only the file changed on `branch1` showed up as a difference. However, in Gitlab I don't get the same result. The files of `branch1` seem to contain all the changes, but when I do a compare (Repository->Compare) and select `branch2` on the left and `branch1` on the right, it says the difference is 69 commits and 42 files, etc.. These are exactly the changes of `branch2` before the merge, which should be in `branch1`, too, now. It seems as if the last commit in `branch1` (the merge) was not part of the compare. Why is it not comparing the last commits of each branch?

[image]

A similar thing in the graph view (`branch1` selected): I would expect some kind of connection between the two branches.

[image]

Comment: I can't speak specifically for Gitlab, having never used it, but in Git in general, a "squash merge" is not a merge at all. You do it when you intend to *kill off* the branch being merged, discarding all commits reachable only from that branch, in favor of a *single commit* that produces the result you would have gotten, had you used a real merge.

Comment: I guess that explains the disconnected graph display, but why does the compare view show all the changes when they should be on both branches?

Comment: I don't know: that particular "compare" does not seem to mean "compare contents of branch tip commits", but what it *does* mean, I don't know. (Hm, the three dots in the display suggests maybe it's equivalent to `git rev-list A...B` with three dots; that would list the commits reachable from either branch tip, but not from both.)